# Yes or No radio button to display a different DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a yes or no questionaire for perfroming a test. If they answer yes to the first question then they are presented the second question and so forth. If they answer no to any of them it will tell them to contact the administrator and it will provide the POC.

I'm usinig this fiddle as my basis but I can't get it to work when I try to add the no option to display the POC.

```
Do you see the color red? Yes or No
```

If they select Yes then the next question will appear

```
Do you see the color blue? Yes or No
```

Once a No is selected the questions stop and it says contact your systems administrators.

http://jsfiddle.net/mail2zam/vQ4Up/

```
   <form class="form-signin" role="form">
    Do you see the color Red?
        <input type="radio" name="myofficeissue" id="0" value="No">No
        <input type="radio" name="myofficeissue" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv"  id="1" value="Yes">Yes
    <div id="slidingDiv">
    Do you see the color Blue?
        <input type="radio" name="passwordissue" id="passwordissue-0" value="No">No
        <input type="radio" name="passwordissue" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2" id="passwordissue-1" value="Yes">Yes
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="alert-user">Please contact the administrator....</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Would you please edit the question to include all relevant code in the question itself?

Comment: do you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/vQ4Up/7/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
  <form class="form-signin" role="form">
     I am having a Cloud My Office log in issue
    <input type="radio" name="myofficeissue" id="0" value="No">No
    <input type="radio" name="myofficeissue" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv"  id="1" value="Yes">Yes
        <div id="slidingDiv">
            I am having a username and password issue.
          <input type="radio" name="passwordissue" id="passwordissue-0" value="No">No
          <input type="radio" name="passwordissue" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2" id="passwordissue-1" value="Yes">Yes
        </div>   
     <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2"></a><br />
        <div id="slidingDiv_2">
        I need to reset my password
          <input type="radio" name="password" id="password-0" value="No" checked="checked" required> No
          <input type="radio" name="password" id="password-1" value="Yes" required>   Yes
          </br>
            My username needs updated.
          <input type="radio" name="username" id="username-0" value="No" checked="checked" required> No
          <input type="radio" name="username" id="username-1" value="Yes" required> Yes</br>
    My account is locked out
    <input type="radio" name="locked" id="locked-0" value="No" checked="checked" required> No
          <input type="radio" name="locked" id="locked-1" value="Yes" required> Yes</br>
    I am experiencing other problems
          <input type="radio" name="other" id="other-0" value="No" checked="checked" required>No
          <input type="radio" name="other" id="other-1" value="Yes" required>Yes</br>
        </div> 
        <div>
        <div id="alert-user">Please contact the administrator....</div>
        </div>
              </form>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;}

#slidingDiv, #slidingDiv_2, #alert-user{
    display:none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio").change(function(){
        console.log(this);
        if(this.value == 'Yes' && this.name == 'myofficeissue'){
            $('#slidingDiv').slideDown();
            $('#alert-user').slideUp();
        }else if(this.value == 'No' && this.name == 'myofficeissue'){
        $('#alert-user').slideDown();
            $('#slidingDiv').slideUp();
            $('#alert-user').slideUp();
            $('#slidingDiv_2').slideUp();
        }else if(this.value == 'Yes' && this.name == 'passwordissue'){
            $('#slidingDiv_2').slideDown();
            $('#alert-user').slideUp();
        }else if(this.value == 'No' && this.name == 'passwordissue'){
            $('#slidingDiv_2').slideUp();
            $('#alert-user').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ4Up/8/)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I have add alert box in slideup event. that why any one click on ON option alter slider up it's show alert box.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").change(function() {
    console.log(this);
    if (this.value == 'Yes' && this.name == 'myofficeissue') {
      $('#slidingDiv').slideDown();
    } else if (this.value == 'No' && this.name == 'myofficeissue') {
      $('#slidingDiv').slideUp(function() {
        alert('contact your admin');
      });
      $('#slidingDiv_2').slideUp();

    } else if (this.value == 'Yes' && this.name == 'passwordissue') {
      $('#slidingDiv_2').slideDown();
    } else if (this.value == 'No' && this.name == 'passwordissue') {
      $('#slidingDiv_2').slideUp(function() {
        alert('contact your admin');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#slidingDiv,
#slidingDiv_2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-signin" role="form">
  I am having a Cloud My Office log in issue
  <input type="radio" name="myofficeissue" id="0" value="No">No
  <input type="radio" name="myofficeissue" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv" id="1" value="Yes">Yes
  <div id="slidingDiv">
    I am having a username and password issue.
    <input type="radio" name="passwordissue" id="passwordissue-0" value="No">No
    <input type="radio" name="passwordissue" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2" id="passwordissue-1" value="Yes">Yes
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2"></a>
  <br />
  <div id="slidingDiv_2">
    I need to reset my password
    <input type="radio" name="password" id="password-0" value="No" checked="checked" required>No
    <input type="radio" name="password" id="password-1" value="Yes" required>Yes
    </br>
    My username needs updated.
    <input type="radio" name="username" id="username-0" value="No" checked="checked" required>No
    <input type="radio" name="username" id="username-1" value="Yes" required>Yes</br>
    My account is locked out
    <input type="radio" name="locked" id="locked-0" value="No" checked="checked" required>No
    <input type="radio" name="locked" id="locked-1" value="Yes" required>Yes</br>
    I am experiencing other problems
    <input type="radio" name="other" id="other-0" value="No" checked="checked" required>No
    <input type="radio" name="other" id="other-1" value="Yes" required>Yes</br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks perfect solution to me !

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.